# Class that extends ArrayList doesn't serialize properly

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I want to make a custom list that behaves similar to array list except that it has one additional attribute. I created the CustomList class and did the test in the CustomListTest class. However the problem is that the additional attribute doesn't show up in the json serialization. So the code below only prints out [1,2,3]. Is there a way to do this such that the attribute is also included in the serialization?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class CustomList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    private boolean attribute = false;
}

public class CustomListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        CustomList<Integer> a = new CustomList<Integer>();

        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the JSON look like?

Comment: This doesn't work because Jackson library has custom serializer rules for collections - they would be converted to a list of elements like what you showed.

Comment: {"attribute":false,"list":[]}

Comment: @Jai In order to accomplish what I want, would I have to not extend ArrayList but instead wrap that list as an attribute in some class?

Comment: @Jessica I would say that is definitely easier, because Jackson would recognise that as a POJO class and serializes the fields as usual, and it would see this `ArrayList` and serialize it using collection rule.

Comment: If I didn't have to use Jackson serializer, would this(adding an attribute to a class that extends a list) have been a good pattern?

Comment: Almost certainly not. This looks like a classic case of *prefer composition over inheritance*.

Comment: Yup, I would say no one would expect a collection-type class to be used to contain anything other than its elements.

Comment: As a side note, if you still want the attribute inside the list, it is also possible to write your own serialization codes, and tell Jackson this is how you want objects of this class to be serialized. Haven't done that for a year now, so I couldn't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no field with name list. In JSON you cannot add attributes to an array. If you want to get the serialized form 
{"attribute":false,"list":[]}, you would need a Java object like that:

```
private static class ComposeList<T> {
  boolean attribute = false;
  ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

As already said by chylis: "prefer composition over inheritance". This is a general rule in Java. Inheritance makes a design often inflexible.